# insert BibTeX article *here*, not at the end of the article

Tags: bibtex

I've seen this before, but I just can't find it.

I am writing a resume and want to include the articles from my bibtex file. If I write \cite{FOO} then they all appear at the end. I know that there is some way to say \something{FOO} and the FOO reference appears here.

Basically, I want this section of my CV to look like:

```
\something{FOO1}

\something{FOO2}
```

What is the \something?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it. Use the [bibentry](http://gking.harvard.edu/files/bibentry.pdf) package.